# Check nodejs path exists

Tags: javascript, node.js

I only want to know whether a path exists. Here's my code:

```
var path = require('path'); // exists path
```

Comment: So it looks as though if you're just trying to be safe, by checking to see if the file exists before you try an operation on it, that the "NPM way" is to not do so and just handle an error if the operation fails. So e.g. use `fs.readFile()` without first checking if the file exists... (The reason for this has to do with the fact that a file may exist and then when you go to access it it may no longer exist, etc.)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The way to check if a file exists in the filesystem using the `fs.existsSync()` method:

```
const fs = require('fs')

const path = './file.txt';

if (fs.existsSync(path)) {
  //file exists
}
```

This method is synchronous, to check if a file exists in an asynchronous way, you can use `fs.access()`, which checks the existence of a file without opening it:

```
fs.access(path, fs.F_OK, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err)
    return
  }

  //file exists
})
```

Comment: @RahulTripathi really fast :)

Comment: `path.exists()` is deprecated in 0.8.0 and higher. Use `fs.exists()` instead.

Comment: `fs.exists()` will also be [deprecated](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_exists_path_callback). You will probably want to use some version of [stat](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_stat_path_callback).

Comment: It looks like [fs.access()](https://nodejs.org/api/all.html#fs_fs_access_path_mode_callback) is the thing to use.

Comment: please don't encourage people to use `path` as a global string, it clashes with the convention of it being reference to `require('path')`

Comment: `fs.existsSync(path)` is still a valid solution with Node v21